# Knockoutjs multiple bindings error

Tags: knockout.js

Adding of the div with the custom binding "dialog" causes the multiple bindings error.
Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?
The version of knockout used is 3.0.

Please find the code here
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/RBD6mFUeM4U

Answer (score 0):

I've not read your codes completely, but 'this' keyword in every function of JavaScript, will reference to current function, so instead of this.isAddDataSenderDialogVisible(true);
you should writer self.isAddDataSenderDialogVisible(true);
I know may be other errors are remained, but this item should be fixed.

Could you please provide a downloadable project structure, to make testing easier ?

Good luck